# Lower bounds for bb(7) and bb(8) wanted

Tags: turing-machines

The busy beaver function $bb(n)$ is not known for $n \geq 5$. Does Anyone know 
suitable lower bounds for $bb(7)$ and $bb(8)$?

Remark: $bb(6)$ as a trivial lower bound does not count as a suitable bound.

Comment: I don't know any upper bound that is not trivial from bb(6). But perhaps something was published recently ?

Comment: Maybe the people on cstheory.stackexchange.com would be more likely to know about recent developments in this area.

Comment: Heiner Marxen keeps track of bounds and records at http://www.drb.insel.de/~heiner/BB/ Also of possible interest is http://cp4space.wordpress.com/2012/12/30/fast-growing-3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recently on the Googology Wiki, user  Wythagoras modified the Busy Beaver machine for six states to create a seven state machine that prints more than $10^{10^{10^{10^{18705353}}}}$ ones.  The machine is listed [here](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/User_blog%3aWythagoras/A_good_bound_for_S%287%29?), and the computation is verified [here](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/User_blog%3aCloudy176/Proving_the_bound_for_S%287%29). So $S(7) > \Sigma(7) > 10^{10^{10^{10^{18705353}}}}$.

I haven't heard of any good bounds for $\Sigma(8)$.

Comment: A bound much larger than I would have expected!